# Wordpress tags specify category

Tags: php, wordpress

I want display tags from specify category. My code is:

```
<?php $categories = get_categories('post_type=post');  ?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>

<?php  
        $project_query = query_posts('cat='.$category->term_id.'');
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            $posttags = get_the_tags();
            if ($posttags) {
                foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                    $all_tags_arr[] = $tag -> name; 
                }
            }
        endwhile;
    ?><?php echo $category->term_id; ?>
    <?php if ( is_array($all_tags_arr) && count($all_tags_arr) > 0 ): ?>
<?php
    $tags_arr = array_unique($all_tags_arr); 
    foreach( $tags_arr as $tag ):
        $el = get_term_by('name', $tag, 'post_tag');
        $arr[] = '"tag-'.$el->slug.'"';
    ?>
    <span><a href="#<?php echo $el->slug; ?>" id="taglink-tag-<?php echo $el->slug; ?>" rel="tag-<?php echo $el->slug; ?>"><?php echo $el->name; ?></a> </span>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>

 <?php endforeach; wp_reset_query();  ?>
```

and when I used  `query_posts('cat=22')` is work,
I have a problem with `query_posts('cat='.$category->term_id.'')` its doesnt work

Is this a bug in Wordpress or is it something in my code?

---

Its weird when I use before other code `term_id` in `query_post` worked, but I need tag slug name in permalink

```
$query_args = array(
  'category__in' => $category->term_id ,
  'posts_per_page' => -1
)
$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

$posttags = "";
while( $query->have_posts() ) {
  $query->the_post();
    if( get_the_tag_list() ){
      $posttags = $posttags . strip_tags(get_the_tag_list('',',',','));

    }
} 

wp_reset_postdata();
$sortedtags = explode(',', $posttags);
asort($sortedtags);
$sortedtags = array_unique($sortedtags);
$sortedtags = array_values( array_filter($sortedtags) );
foreach ($sortedtags as $tagname) {

  echo '<li><a href="'. home_url() .'/number/'. $category->slug .'?tag=' . $tags . '">' . $tagname . '</a></li>';    

}
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$category->term_id` is 22?

Comment: I create page where display all categories with tags, I mean
category 1 - tag 1, tag 2 etc
category 2 - tag1, tag 3 etc ...

Comment: query_posts('cat='.$category->term_id); try this

Comment: maybe in second code is possible display tag->slug name in permalink?

Comment: I found a problem. Currently show all tags in category, It is possible hide tag if havent posts?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) class to create your loop since using `query_posts` functions is strongly [discouraged](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).
By using `WP_Query` you can easily use the following line to get posts for a specific category or more.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $category->term_id ) );
```

Comment: Make sure your `$category` contains the right data --> `print_r($category);`